# python mysql in order number input to table id

Tags: python, mysql, string, int, pymysql

I m trying to add id s to my table with strings and in order number. Here is the codes:

```
import pymysql.cursors
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='xxx', db='python')


with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create a new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO `arzugulgundogdu2` (`id`) VALUES ('dgNotListesi_txtGelisimDurumu_'%s)"  


        y = int("0")
        while y < 10:

            cursor.execute(sql, (y))
            y = y+1


conn.commit()
```

Also, when i choice a constant value for y in order to while loop, it looks like dgNotListesi_txtGelisimDurumu_'myconstanthere.
why is there a ' signature between string and my y variable?
Thanks. I m pretty new to python :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why is there a ' signature between string and my y variable?

That's because you have this extra single quote here before the placeholder:

```
... 'dgNotListesi_txtGelisimDurumu_'%s
                               HERE^
```

Instead make the complete value in Python and parameterize the query with it:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `arzugulgundogdu2` (`id`) VALUES (%s)" 

value = "dgNotListesi_txtGelisimDurumu_%s" % y
cursor.execute(sql, (y, ))
```